# Why can't I import a variable multiple times?

Tags: python, variables, import

Why am I not able to import a `variable` that is in `game.py`, `WIDTH, HEIGHT` - into `player.py` and `enemy.py` at the same time? I can only import it into one file.

When I import it on both files.
I get the following error:

```
from game import HEIGHT, WIDTH
ImportError: cannot import name HEIGHT
```

## Game.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
VERSION = "0.1"
import os, sys, player, enemy
from os import path

try:
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
except ImportError, err:
    print 'Could not load module %s' % (err)
    sys.exit(2)

# main variables
WIDTH, HEIGHT, FPS, BGIMG = 700, 400, 30, 'FlappyTrollbg.jpg'

# initialize game
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("FlappyTroll - Python2.7")

# background
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((255,255,255))

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')
class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = WIDTH
        self.height = HEIGHT
        self.image = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,image_file)).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(self.width,self.height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = location
        self.speedx = 5
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.speedx
        if self.rect.x <= -WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = WIDTH

# blitting
screen.blit(background,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

# clock for FPS settings
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def main():
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bgs = pygame.sprite.Group()
    creature = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bgs.add(Background(BGIMG, [0,0]))
    bgs.add(Background(BGIMG, [WIDTH,0]))
    creature.add(player.FlappyTroll())
    for i in range(0,4):
        all_sprites.add(enemy.TrollEnemy())
    # variable for main loop
    running = True
    # init umbrella
    # event loop
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

    #    gets_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(umb, all_sprites, True)
    #    if gets_hit:
    #        newDrop()
        screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
        # update
        bgs.update()
        all_sprites.update()
        creature.update()
        # draw
        bgs.draw(screen)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        creature.draw(screen)

        # flip the table
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## player.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from os import path
from random import randint
from game import HEIGHT, WIDTH

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')

class FlappyTroll(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = 64
        self.height = 64
        self.image = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"flappytroll.png")).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(self.width,self.height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.width*2
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT/2-self.height
        self.speedy = 5

    def update(self):
        pass
    #    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #    if(keys[pygame.K_SPACE]):
    #        self.rect.y -= self.speedy*2
    #    else:
    #        self.rect.y += self.speedy
```

## enemy.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from os import path
from random import randint
from game import HEIGHT, WIDTH

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')

class TrollEnemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = 64
        self.height = 64
        self.image = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"TrollEnemy.png")).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(self.width,self.height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = WIDTH+self.width
        self.rect.y = randint(self.height,HEIGHT-self.height)
        self.speedy = 5

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= speedy
```

Comment: Why do you need to import a variable?

Comment: If it's in main.py then you should be doing `from main ...`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Well, it's called game.py but i wrote main here. Updating now.

Comment: does enemy import player or vice versa?

Comment: You have a circular import problem. It's not because two files are importing the same file; it's because a chain of imports from some file is leading back to that file.

Comment: @Sklert I have `from game import HEIGHT, WIDTH` in both player.py and enemy.py

Comment: @user2357112 is there a work-around for this problem?

Comment: @IdontReallywolf: Restructure your code to remove the circular import.

Comment: I asked you, if player.py imports enemy.py or enemy.py imports player

Comment: @Sklert They don't import eachother.

Comment: so what does "at the same time" mean? You try something like `python player.py` and then `python enemy.py` and error occures?

Comment: @Sklert Let me post all three files here.

Comment: Well, you are importing `player` and `enemy` in `game.py`! _circular imports_

Comment: As user2357112 mentioned, you have a circular import problem. I assume you wanna run game.py. In the third line you import player, so Python parses that file. As the parser reaches the fifth line of player.py, it is supposed to import game.py. There's your circular import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user2357112 mentioned, you have a circular import problem. I assume you wanna run game.py. In the third line you import player, so Python parses that file. As the parser reaches the fifth line of player.py, it is supposed to import game.py. There's your circular import.

To solve this, you could define your main variables in a separate .py (easy) or .ini (more complicated but also cleaner) file and import them from there.

Another option is to just not import the main variables and pass them to every function that needs them instead. To do that, you could group them into a dictionary so that you have only one object to pass around.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now I see that you really have circular import. Your `game.py` try to import `player.py` and `enemy.py`. When you import variables from game.py, python imports `game.py` and [creates references in the current namespace to the given objects](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) So `game.py` imports `player.py`, which imports `game.py`. It is called "circular import".

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a file called `config.py` and added the variables there. Then imported `config.py` into all files. Works fine now xD

Comment: @IdontReallywolf a very sensible approach.